# Why is the computed property of this component not reactive:

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object like this:

```
  myObject: {
    items: [{
      title: '140',
      isActive: true,
    }, {
      title: '7',
      isActive: false
    }, {
      title: '10',
      isActive: false
    }]
  }
```

Which I'm using like this:

```
<my-component :items="myObject.items"></my-component>
```

This is how the component looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="i-panel panel-container d-flex"
    <div
      v-for="item in prefs.items"
      class="panel-item"
      @click="onClick(item)">
      <!-- some content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'IPanel',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default () {
        return []
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    // code
    prefs () {
      return {
        items: this.items
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onClick (item) {
      this.prefs.items.forEach(item => {
        if (JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(clickedItem)) {
          item.isActive = true
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click an item (and that `item` is the same as the `clickedItem`), it's supposed to become `isActive` `true`. It does. But I have to refresh the Vue devtools or re-render the page for the change to take effect.

Why isn't `item.isActive = true` reactive?

Comment: In your `onClick` method, you are using a `clickedItem`object, but I can't see it defined anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<div
  v-for="item in prefs.items"
  class="panel-item"
  @click="onClick(item)">
  <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

to

```
<div
  v-for="(item, index) in prefs.items"
  class="panel-item"
  @click="onClick(index)">
  <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

Then, in your change method, go like this:

```
onClick (index) {
  Vue.set(this.items, index, true);
}
```

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, you are using a clickedItem object that is not defined anywhere. I don't know if this is just in the process of writing your question or if it is your problem.

However, when using `clickedItem` the right way, it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/d5z93ygy/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="app" class="i-panel panel-container d-flex">
    <div
      v-for="item in prefs.items"
      class="panel-item"
      @click="onClick(item)">
      <!-- some content -->{{ item.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [{
      title: '140',
      isActive: true,
    }, {
      title: '7',
      isActive: false
    }, {
      title: '10',
      isActive: false
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    // code
    prefs () {
      return {
        items: this.items
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick (clickedItem) {
      this.prefs.items.forEach(item => {
        if (JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(clickedItem)) {
          item.isActive = true
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Side note: you should not mutate your props directly and rather make a copy of your props to work with them: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated